# JOOQ delete with join

Tags: postgresql, sql-delete, jooq

How can I write a JOOQ delete query to join on a field from a `with` clause? Is it possible?

I have an SQL query that is working but I don't know how to convert it to JOOQ.

This is my query:

```
with "temp" as (
    select field1 as field1
    from "table"
             join ("table2")
                  on (table.field1 = table2.field2)
)
delete from table using temp
where table.field1 = temp.field1;
```

I tried:

```
transactionDSLContext.with("temp")
dsl.as(
                                    select(TABLE.FIELD1.as("field1"))
                                            .from(TABLE)
                                            .join(TABLE2)
                                            .on(TABLE.FIELD1.eq(TABLE2.FIELD2))

                            )
                            .delete(TABLE)
                            .where(TABLE.FIELD1.eq((Field<String>) temp.field("field1"))
                            .execute();
```

But I'm getting:

```
ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "temp"
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `using` clause:

```java
.delete(TABLE).using(temp)
```

I'm assuming that you have a local variable `temp` where you assigned your `CommonTableExpression`...

Comment: I don't have it as an option... only delete(TABLE).where(...)

Comment: Well, it was added in jOOQ 3.13: https://www.jooq.org/api-diff/3.12-3.13